# Bukkit: Set a block powered

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to get into bukkit programming for minecraft, but for some reason I'm stuck with trying to set a block powered.
I don't want do set a redstone-torch under the block.

I tried to change the data to an active lever.
If there is anyone who can help me, please.

Code I tried:

```
Block n = my block;
Block block = your lever;
Lever l = (Lever) block;
l.setPowered(true); //toggles on
n.setData(l.getData());
```

Comment: What kind of block are you trying to power?

Comment: I would like to power a HAY_BLOCK 
Other blocks are ok too (If that is just working with some blocks)

Comment: Why exactly do you need to power a hay_block? It's not a block that requires Redstone Power

Comment: Because I want to test AND circuit :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible to power a block that isn't a PowerableBlock. What you can do is check for a BlockRedstoneEvent, to check if the block received power, and then power redstone behind it. But that would only work if there's any redstone connected to it providing current. Would that be of any help?

Comment: Yeah it's better than nothing ^_^
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to power a block that's not a Powerable Block directly.

However, you can do some tricks to pretend it's powered:

Detect whenever you want your block to power nearby blocks (for example onInteractEvent), and then send power to the blocks.

```
@EventHandler
public void onInteractEvent(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
Block interacted = e.getClickedBlock();
//Check if this is the block you want

Block block= interacted.getRelative(BlockFace.UP, 1);    //Can be changed to any block face, and any distance


switch(block.getType()) {
case LEVER:
case REDSTONE:
case DISPENSER:
case POWERED_RAILS:
case whatever other blocks can be powered:
{
      block.setData(block.getData() | 0x8); // sets the 0x8 bit to the data, making it powered
} }
```