# Emit redstone signal to a block Bukkit 1.12.2

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

*First of all, this is the first time I create a Bukkit plugin.*

Basically, when someone does a certain action with a block and checks certain conditions, I would like it to **emit a redstone signal** (the block). The code is executed in the Bukkit **PlayerInteractEvent**.
Except that after a lot of research, I still haven't found a single (working) solution, neither on the forums, nor in the documentation.

I don't know how to **tell Minecraft that this block can emit redstone** (*if it needs it*). If I don't say anything stupid, it was created with a **dynamX pack** (the mod that contains the block).

I already looked at this solution: [Bukkit: Set a block powered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376835/bukkit-set-a-block-powered), but it doesn't match my expectations and doesn't work.

So I was wondering if it was possible to **emit a redstone signal on a specific block** with **Bukkit 1.12.2**, or at a **specific coordinate**. This would solve all the problems related to this.

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it seems that it is **not possible** for bukkit to set a block as a redstone source.
However, you can trick the game by temporary replacing the block by a redstone emitter :

1. The PlayerInteractEvent is emitted, and the conditions you specified are checked.
2. You temporary replace the block that you clicked for 2 ticks by a redstone block
3. After those 2 ticks, you replace the redstone block by the original block

This solution might not work for you, but it is the best that i could find.

Comment: So it would be better to do it via a mod?

Comment: I think it would be better to do it with a mod yes

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**
You could try getting the blocks around it, check if they're of type redstone powder and set them to active.

So that in a way it would be emitting power to nearby redstone. Although it won't act quite as much as a redstone source.

---

**Solution 2:**
Use a custom resource pack, add a 2nd variant of the redstone block and set its textures to your block of choice.
When placed, it will look like your block but in acutality it'd be a redstone block.

Doing it this way, you'll have the most accurate redstone emittion.